# Did a Subaru "Puddle Light Flaw" Exist?

Tags: electrical, subaru

A universal issue regarding a factory flaw with the Puddle Lights?

It seemed to be universal, affecting SG-era Foresters (Impreza Platform) and Legacy Platform 3rd and 4th gen OB's etc, as well.

Other issues can include malfunction of steering-mounted controls, including cruise control, wipers, head lights, horn and mobile phone use.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you are referring to?

> Blockquote
>   In accordance with 49 CFR Part 573, “Defect and Noncompliance Responsibility and Reports,” Fuji Heavy Industries USA, Inc. on behalf of Subaru of America, Inc. and Fuji Heavy Industries, Ltd., submits the enclosed notification and report concerning a defect in the Puddle Light on all 2010 and 2011MY Subaru Legacy and Outback vehicles, certain 2006MY through 2012MY Tribeca vehicles sold before January 2012 , and certain 2009MY through 2012MY Forester vehicles sold before January 2012 in the United States. Our internal designation for this recall campaign will be: WQE-41.
>   If you have any questions on the enclosed report, please contact me at (443) 430-3619 or jfro@subaru.com.

Source: http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/acms/cs/jaxrs/download/doc/UCM431591/RCDNN-12V602-9293.pdf

Other sources:
https://www.carcomplaints.com/Subaru/Forester/2011/recalls/accessory-puddle-light-may-short-circuit-12v602000.shtml

http://www.wqe41.service-campaign.com/

https://www.caradvice.com.au/371561/subaru-impreza-xv-forester-recalled-for-electrical-fault/

http://www.cars101.com/recalls.html